# Angular 4: " SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught" polyfill error in IE 9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

My application use Angular 4.0.0 and "angular-polyfills": "^1.0.1", it works in all browsers except IE9

I uncommented all the lines in **polyfills.ts** file

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

I got this **error** in IE9

```
     try {
                return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            // if the task's state is notScheduled or unknown, then it has already been cancelled
            // we should not reset the state to scheduled
            if (task.state !== notScheduled && task.state !== unknown) {
                if (task.type == eventTask || (task.data && task.data.isPeriodic)) {
                    reEntryGuard && task._transitionTo(scheduled, running);
```

Do i have to include any other polyfills file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There is a polygon.ts file that has commented code that says to uncomment for IE9 support.